# Pass to method object values as arguments

Tags: javascript

I have next code:

```
someFunct(Object.values(Obj));
```

What I need is to pass object values in to 'someFunct' as separate argument, not as array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the spreading operator to spread the values:

```
someFunct(...Object.values(Obj));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use spread operator `...`

```
someFunct(...Object.values(Obj));
```

**Note:** This method may cause some problems in code because `Object.values()` is not guaranteed to have same order. The better option is to pass and object and then destructure it.